# How do I export my Unity Vuforia project to exe

Tags: unity-game-engine, export, exe, vuforia

Whenever I export my vuforia unity project to exe it just apears black

Answer (score 0):

I believe we can export it as .apk for android and .ipa file for Ios.In File - build settings we can choose the suitable platform by switching platform.After that u can take the build for corresponding platforms.If device is connected you can build and run.